# Migration from Angular 1.2.x to 1.3.x or 1.4.x

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

I have code

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event){
      User.refresh();

      if(!User.isLoggedIn()){
        event.preventDefault();
        $location.path('/sign_in');
      } else {
        if($location.path() == "/sign_in"){
          $location.path("/");
        };
      };
    });
```

I changed `"angular-route": "~1.4.0",` then $location.path('/sign_in') does not work. If i comment out `event.preventDefault();` this works fine. This is the same case when i use `~1.3.0`. Can any one tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: put the event.prventDefault() after the $location.path('/sign_in');

Comment: Try this : 
            $rootScope.$evalAsync(function() {
                    $location.path('/sign_in');
                 });

Comment: I want to know why event.preventDefault is actually stopping $location.path("/sign_in");

Comment: @Astro it's the same behaviour after doing it

Comment: why you put event.preventDefault(); i think no need...caz, $location.path("/sign_in"); redirects to the new controller function.So just remove it.

Comment: I did that the moment I realized, I asked the question to understand why its not working.

Answer (score 0):

i run in the same problem and found answers here:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/9678

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/9607

on Version 1.3 and 1.4 angular calls with $location.path('/sign_in') the $routeChangeStart event.

So you get an infinite Loop. If you use event.preventDefault(); this loop breaks.

Comment: explain the solution a little and what have you learned from that issue .